# SAML2 assertion with home defined AttributeBean in CXF

Tags: xml, cxf, saml, attr

I’ve been working with Apache CXF and WSS4J to implement a SecurityTokenService.

Using a “CustomClaimsHandler” implementing "org.apache.cxf.sts.claims.ClaimsHandler" I can create a SAML token containing this kind of attributes :

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
               <saml2:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">admin</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

The thing is I am now trying to create an attribute with some XML content. For exemple :

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="http://my/xml/content">
               <saml2:AttributeValue xsi:type="???">
        <somthing>
<somthingElse>text</somthingElse>
        </somthing>
</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

Following a response I got on this link : [SAML2 xml structured attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724098/saml2-xml-structured-attribute-values)

I added a dependency to opensaml-core v3.0.0 in my CXF STS project to obtain the “org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport” class as shown in the exemple from the response. 
Before calling  the XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getBuilderFactory() I seemed to have to initialize the configuration of opensaml.

I managed the initialization calling “org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize();”

All seems good for the creation of the AttributeBean with an XSAny type.

The problem is when WSS4J tries to  Handle the SAMLCallback :

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.xml.XMLObjectBuilder
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.initializeObjectProviders(XMLConfigurator.java:236)
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:182)
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:166)
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:143)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.saml.OpenSAMLBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(OpenSAMLBootstrap.java:105)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.saml.OpenSAMLBootstrap.bootstrap(OpenSAMLBootstrap.java:86)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.saml.OpenSAMLUtil.initSamlEngine(OpenSAMLUtil.java:61)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.saml.SamlAssertionWrapper.(SamlAssertionWrapper.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.sts.token.provider.SAMLTokenProvider.createSamlToken(SAMLTokenProvider.java:303)
    at org.apache.cxf.sts.token.provider.SAMLTokenProvider.createToken(SAMLTokenProvider.java:122)
    ... 45 more`

Maybe I have a version issue :

Either I’d have to make my STS’s configuration of opensaml aware of my opensaml-core v3.0.0 classes ? 
Or I’d have to use a different version of CXF to get a newer version of WSS4J ?

My version of CXF is 3.0.1 and has a dependency on WSS4J-ws-security-common  in version 2.0.1 witch has a dependency on opensaml version 2.6.1

Does someone have a clue ?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use OpenSAML 3 with CXF 3.0.x or WSS4J 2.0.x. If you really need to use OpenSAML 3, then you will need to work with the CXF master SNAPSHOT code (3.1.0-SNAPSHOT), which is currently working with OpenSAML 3.

Colm.

Comment: Thanks once again Colm !

Comment: I am using OpenSAML 3 and CXF 3.2.1, but I still get this issue. How do I resolve?